# Entity Framework Core Database First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, ef-database-first

My team has inherited a database application that contains hundreds of tables. The application uses Entity Framework and takes a database first approach for development. Our current process is to pull a table or two at a time into the edmx using the `Update Model From Database...` tool.

We are considering making a new API with .Net Core, but as far as I can tell from the research I have done, there is no equivalent process in the `Entity Framework Core` tools. The closest thing I can find is to reverse engineer the entire database with `Scaffold-DbContext`, and then use migrations for all future database changes. We can't scaffold the entire database, because some of the tables have errors, and fixing all those errors is not a viable option for us right now.

I have found that I can supply a list of tables that I want scaffolded with the initial `Scaffold-DbContext` call, but I'm not sure if migrations can be used in a similar way to the `Update Model From Database...` tool. Can I use migrations to add tables that already exist in our database? If not, what other options should I be looking at?

Comment: migrations are used to alter the database, usually for ALTER/CREATE/DROP statements or seeding tables. You can add tables to an EF code first set of classes as you see fit (on an as needed basis). You do not have to run migrations between library versions unless you want to change the schema (as already stated above). The objects/(tables) that are not mapped will be ignored.

Comment: @Igor Do those need to be added manually, or is there a way to reverse engineer them like the initial Scaffold-DbContext?

Comment: You have to add them manually *but* there might be tools available to help with this. You can do a [web search](http://google.com) on this, be sure to include your RDBMS in the search terms.

Comment: You don't _have_ to use Migrations, and in this scenario you probably shouldn't.  You re-run Scaffold-DbContext after database changes to regenerate the entity types, or alter them by hand to match the changed tables.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft In this scenario, would I need to use the -Force option to recreate all the files that I previously generated? Can this be done by only listing the tables I want to add, or would I need to continue listing all tables that currently exist in the application as well as the new ones each time I re-run Scaffold-DbContext?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I typically manually sync the entities after the initial scaffolding, or completely regenerate the entities in a separate project and copy them in.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I was thinking about a temp directory for output and copying generated files, but it seems like the <DBName>Context.cs file gets big fast, so I wasn't sure how well that would work. Maybe I could store the database list in a config file and open it from a script in the package manager console so that I can regenerate the entire thing each time.